# react-router-dom not updating useParmams() when Link to same path with different url

Tags: reactjs, react-router

It renders fine if I click the link in the `<MeetNew>` component from a different component, but when a `<MeetNew>` `Link` is clicked from the `<User>` component, the page doesn't load correctly.

on the component

```
const User = () => {
  let { id } = useParams()
  let res2;
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({
    user: {},
    listItems: []
  })

  const { listItems } = userInfo

  useEffect(() => async () => {
    try {
      if (id) {
        const res2 = await axios.get(`/api/listItems/${id}`)
        setUserInfo({ listItems: res2.data })
        console.log('render')
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  }, [id])

  return (
  ...
  )
```

I feel like I'm not using `useParams()` correctly or `useEffect` correctly. When I click the link the URL change is correct, but `useParams()` doesn't re-render or re-mount my component.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are referring to pages as components? Is it possible that your `id` param does not change, so your useEffect is not activated, thus there is no loading of items?

Comment: I console.log(id) at the end of the 'try' inside the 'if' statement. It's changing correctly according to my browser

Answer (score 0):

The `useEffect` looks very suspect to me. It doesn't run any logic as part of the ***effect*** *other than* to return an `async` cleanup function. This probably isn't what you meant to implement.

Refactor the `useEffect` callback to declare an `async` function and only invoke it if there is a truthy `id` dependency value.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getItems = async () => {
    try {
      const res2 = await axios.get(`/api/listItems/${id}`);
      setUserInfo({ listItems: res2.data });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }

  if (id) {
    getItems();
  }
}, [id]);
```

What I *suspect* is happening is that you are using `react@18` and rendering the app into a `React.StrictMode` component. In `react@18` the `StrictMode` component *intentionally* "double-mounts" react components as a way to ensure [Reusable State](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state). The returned cleanup function runs and makes the GET request and the state is updated. The only occurs on the initial mounting/render of the component, subsequent renders occur normally. This part is just a hunch though by looking at *just* your code without testing a running demo.